# Terraform interpolation - convert string to list

Tags: terraform, string-interpolation

How can I transform a string `"foo, bar, xid, uid"` to a list `["foo", "bar", "xid", "uid"]`?

I'm assigninng to variable value from Consul which is a string

```
my_var = "foo, bar, xid, uid"
```

Now I would like to convert `my_var` to a list that will look like this:

```
my_list = ["foo", "bar", "xid", uid"]
```

How can I achieve that? I was trying to use `formatlist` and the splat operator for that but no success

```
my_list = ${formatlist(<put magic here>, var.my_var)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`split` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#split-delim-string-) here:

```
my_list = ${split(",", var.my_var)}
```

Comment: If you found the answer useful and it completely solved your problem you should consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to show that to others who might have the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

ydaetskcoR's answer is essentially correct, but in Terraform **0.12** syntax has changed, and the split function line should read:

```
my_list = split(",", var.my_var)
```

Comment: We probably want to have a think as a community about how we handle things that are pure syntax updates due to HCL2. I am unsure whether we should leave things as is or whether we should follow the Terraform docs and move everything to HCL2 with a series of edits of existing posts once they consider 0.12 and HCL2 adoption to be complete enough that the provider docs all change. I don't think there's a huge amount of value in duplicating every HCL1 post with the HCL2 syntax.